# Converting to CHAR losing daylight saving

Tags: oracle, timestamp-with-timezone

I have the following query:

```
SELECT
    from_tz(CAST(e.Event_Time_UTC AS TIMESTAMP), 'UTC') AS UTC,
    from_tz(CAST(e.Event_Time_UTC AS TIMESTAMP), 'UTC') AT TIME ZONE 'Brazil/East' AS BRT,
    TO_CHAR(from_tz(CAST(e.Event_Time_UTC AS TIMESTAMP), 'UTC') AT TIME ZONE 'Brazil/East', 'HH24:MI') AS Hora
FROM 
    MY_EVENTS e
ORDER BY 
    UTC
```

I`m getting the UTC time and converting to local.

Everything works fine when I convert directly, but when I use the TO_CHAR, I lose the Daylight saving and end up with the result looking like this:

[image: query_result]

Can someone please explain what`s happening, please?

EDIT: Here's the result from `v$timezone_file`:

[image: v$timezone_file]

Comment: I am not seeing this behavior on my copy of Oracle. `with e (event_time_utc) as ( select to_timestamp('17/10/16 13:30:00', 'dd/mm/yy hh24:mi:ss') from dual )
SELECT..... FROM e` produces the same result, 11:30, in the last two columns.

Comment: Do you think it may have something to do with version? Mine is 10.2.0.4.0

Comment: I would be surprised.... not sure. There is no reason for `to_char()` to change the hour (no reason I can think of, that is).

Comment: The only thing I see is that it's not getting the Daylight saving.

Comment: I was messing around and saw that EXTRACT(HOUR FROM BRT) gives the same result as 'HORA'

Comment: I can replicate in 10.2.0.5 (although the extract gives me 14, not 11), but not in 11.2.0.2/4. Wonder if it's something to do with the time zone file version - what does `v$timezone_file` show? (My 10g shows 4; there are changes to Brazil/East in versions 10, 9 and 7). Not sure why it would effect some things but not others though.

Comment: See MOS note 412160.1 for more on timzeone files and how to update it. It might be worth doing that, to a supported version for you DB (see section c1c of that doc.; v26 can be applied to 10.2.0.4 with another patch), but this seems to be fixed by v14 or earlier. *If* that is the problem, but I think it's likely to be related.

Comment: @AlexPoole sorry for the delay on the reply, and thanks for the ideas. I will be checking on those. Will edit soon to show `v$timezone_file`

Comment: Although the inconsistent behaviour is weird, ultimately I think you need to update your timezone file to at least version 10 (last time Brazil/East changed I believe) to get the current rules - so your DB know when DST really ended this year.

Comment: @AlexPoole Thanks, I will talk to my dba to do that.